# scale in one direction in blender doesn't work

Tags: modeling, transforms

in blender 3 , there is some times that scale in one axis just doesn't work seams like some times it wanted to keep the scale uniform , of course i have to apply rotation and scale to be able to scale that specific object in one direction again , any thoughts about that why is this happening ?

The scaling is happening in object mode , i will add a GIF evidence as soon as i face this again .

ok this happens in linked and rotated objects mostly :

[image]

Comment: Are you scaling in _Object Mode_ or _Edit Mode_?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett The scaling is happening in object mode , i will add a GIF evidence as soon as i face this again .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uneven scaling will not work if the object is rotated, because it requires shear. It is not supported in object mode. So only scaling in local axis is supported.

This is the [message from Ton Roosendaal](https://developer.blender.org/T29633#140467) about this problem:

> Blender objects use three vectors (loc, rot, size) to define matrices.
> These matrices are always generated based on that. The obvious benefit
> is for animating loc/rot/size values :) For tools we have to map
> matrices back to loc/rot/size, that's the problem.
>
> This issue is as old as Blender, many have tried to fix :)

Comment: i did test this in another software , and it was able to scale the rotated object , and did you mean this is a bug or something ?

Comment: This is known limitation. Blender was designed not use shear in object mode

Comment: why is that working when i apply rotation ?

Comment: Because in this case local axis meets global axis.

Comment: this is beyond whats my brain is capable of

Comment: This is simple. Then Local axis and Global axis meet, it is ok. If not - you just scale in 3 directions or use local transform instead global.